# Write a program that multiplies user entered number till product of these numbers reach 1000

Tags: c

I've trying to do it for about an hour, but I can't seem to get it right. How is it done?

The code I have at the moment is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    int j=-1;
    while(j<0){
        printf("Enter a number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &j);
    }
    int i=j;
    for(i=j; i<=100; i++){
        printf("%d \n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not able to get the question correctly. explain your question clearly.

Comment: Write a program that multiplies user entered number till product of these numbers reach 1000

Answer (score 3):

The original specification (before code was added) was a little vague but, in terms of the process to follow, that's irrelevant. Let's *assume* they're as follows:

- get two numbers from the user.
- if their product is greater than a thousand, print it and stop.
- otherwise, print product and go back to first bullet point.

(if that's not *quite* what you're after, the *process* is still the same, you just have to adjust the individual steps).

Translating that in to pseudo-code is often a first good step when developing. That would give you something like:

```
def program:
    set product to -1
    while product <= 1000:
        print prompt asking for numbers
        get num1 and num2 from user
        set product to num1 * num2
        print product
    print "target reached"
```

From that point, it's a matter of converting the pseudo-code into a formal computer language, which is generally close to a one-to-one mapping operation.

A good first attempt would be along the lines of:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int num1, num2, product = -1;
    while (product < 1000) {
        printf ("Please enter two whole numbers, separated by a space: ");
        scanf ("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
        product = num1 * num2;
        printf ("Product is %d\n", product);
    }
    puts ("Target reached");
    return 0;
}
```

although there will no doubt be problems with this since it doesn't *robustly* handle invalid input. However, at the level you're operating, it would be a good start.

---

In terms of the code you've supplied (which probably should have been in the original question, though I've added it now):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    int j=-1;
    while(j<0){
        printf("Enter a number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &j);
    }
    int i=j;
    for(i=j; i<=100; i++){
        printf("%d \n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

a better way to do the final loop would be along the lines of:

```
int i = 1;
while (i < 1000) {
    i = i * j;
    printf ("%n\n", i);
}
```

This uses the correct terminating condition of the multiplied number being a thousand or more rather than what you had, a fixed number  of multiplications.

You may also want to catch the possibility that the user enters one, which would result in an infinite loop.

---

A (relatively) professional program to do this would be similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    // Get starting point, two or more.

    int start = 0;
    while (start < 2) {
        printf("Enter a number greater than one: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &start) != 1) {
            // No integer available, clear to end of input line.

            for (int ch = 0; ch != '\n'; ch = getchar());
        }
    }

    // Start with one, continue while less than a thousand.

    int curr = 1;
    while (curr < 1000) {
        // Multiply then print.

        curr *= start;
        printf ("%d\n", curr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This has the following features:

- more suitable variable names.
- detection and repair of most invalid input.
- comments.

That code is included just as an educational example showing how to do a reasonably good job. If you use it as-is for your classwork, don't be surprised if your educators fail you for plagiarism. I'm pretty certain most of them would be using web-search tools to detect that sort of stuff.

Comment: The question is to enter one number and have it multiply itself till it reaches 1000. this is what I wrote but it isn't right!

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    
    int j=-1;
    
    while(j<0){
    
    printf("Enter a number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    }
    
    int i=j;
         for(i=j; i<=100; i++){
            
            printf("%d \n", i);
            
        }
    
    return 0;
}

Comment: @user5435016, that's fine but the steps in my answer still stand. Write it down in pseudo-code until you're happy it would do the correct thing, then translate that into C.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% clear on what you are asking for so I'm assuming the following that you want to get user to keep on entering numbers (I've assumed positive integers) until the all of them multiplied together is greater than or equal to 1000).

The code here starts with the value 1 (because starting with 0 will mean it will never get to anything other than 0) and multiples positive integers to it while the product of all of them remains under 1000. Finally it prints the total (which may be over 1000) and also the number of values entered by the user.

I hope this helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char input[10];
    unsigned currentTotal = 1;
    unsigned value;
    unsigned numEntered = 0;

    while( currentTotal < 1000 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a number: \n" );
        fgets( input, sizeof(input), stdin );
        value = atoi( input );
        if( value > 0 )
        {
            currentTotal *= value;
            numEntered += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "Please enter a positive integer value\n" );
        }
    }

    printf( "You entered %u numbers which when multiplied together equal %u\n", numEntered, currentTotal );

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int input,output=1;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d",&input);
        if(input<=0)
            printf("Please enter a positive integer not less than 1 :\n");
        else if(input>0)
            output*=input;
        if(output>1000)
        {
            printf("\nThe result is: %d",output);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```